# move_uploaded_file não funciona corretamente

Tags: php, syntax-error

Já tentei de todas as maneiras fazer o [move_uploaded_file()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.move-uploaded-file.php) mover o arquivo desejado.

Montei um formulário simples de upload de imagem, porém não move de jeito nenhum.

POST:

```
$foto = $_FILES["txtFoto"];

// Caminho de onde ficará a imagem 
$caminho_imagem = "images/"; 

// Faz o upload da imagem para seu respectivo caminho 
if (move_uploaded_file($foto['name'], $caminho_imagem)) {
    $uploaddir = 'images/'.$foto['name'];
    if(isset($_GET['d'])){
        $id = $_GET['d'];
        produtos::altera($id,$nome,$descricao,$uploaddir);
        $dados = produtos::carrega($id);
    }else{
        produtos::cadastra($nome,$descricao,$uploaddir);
    }
?>
    <div class="alert alert-success" id="respyes">Produto alterado/cadastrado com sucesso!</div>
<?php   
} else {
    echo "nome do arquivo '". $foto['name'] . "'.";
}
```

Esse é uma parte do meu código e já olhei permissão de pastas, sintaxe e todo o resto, mas não funciona :(

Comment: A primeira coisa que precisa ser notada é que o uso de move_uploaded_file está errado, a forma como o colega @deoliveiralucas postou está correta. Segundo a pasta images está criada?(lembrando que elas estará na mesma pasta do script), ela tem as permissões corretas?

Answer (score 1):

Já tentou utilizar o `tmp_name`? assim:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($foto['tmp_name'], $caminho_imagem . $foto['name'])) {
```

Comment: Já sim. E mesmo assim não funcionou x.x

Comment: O que esse código que você postou está retornando? o que retorna o `var_dump($foto)`?

Comment: O var_dump dele retorna os dados corretos da imagem que estou usando para teste:

`array(5) { ["name"]=> string(17) "touch60.png" ["type"]=> string(9) "image/png" ["tmp_name"]=> string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\php8492.tmp" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(3756) } `

Comment: tenta assim: `if (move_uploaded_file($foto['name'], 'images/'.$foto['name'])) {`

Comment: Já havia tentado antes e tentei novamente agora e não funcionou :(

Comment: Esse código está caindo na condição `if` ou `else`?

Comment: Já checou as permissões de pasta?

Answer (score 0):

Tenta a seguinte alteração:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['txtFoto']['tmp_name'], $caminho_imagem.$_FILES['txtFoto']['name']);
```